# Change color of circles using keys

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to figure out how to change the color of the next circle to be drawn using keys, r for red, b for blue etc. I have a working code below which allows me to draw circles of certain sizes on a cavas. I just need to figure out how to implement the char code functions to change the color of the circles

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<body >
<div id="images"></div>
<canvas id= "circles" width="600" height="450" style="border:1px solid #000000;" onclick="draw(event)"></canvas>
<label for="radius">Enter circle radius:</label> <input name="radius"   id="radius" required autofocus />
<button onclick="reset()">reset!</button>
<script src="lab_14MouseClick.js">
var canvas = document.getElementById("circles");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function createImageOnCanvas(imageId) {
canvas.style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("images").style.overflowY = "hidden";
var img = new Image(300, 300);
img.src = document.getElementById(imageId).src;
context.drawImage(img, (0), (0)); //onload....
}

function draw(e) {
var radius=document.getElementById("radius").value;

var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
posx = pos.x;
posy = pos.y;
context.fillStyle = "#000000";
context.beginPath();
context.arc(posx, posy, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
context.fill();

}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
return {
  x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
  y: evt.clientY - rect.top
};
}

window.draw = draw;
function reset() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("circles");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = canvas.width;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

this is the code I am thinking of using to make the circles change colors, I am just not sure of how to add it in

```
function blue (event) {
var x = event.charCode || event.keyCode;
if (x == 66 || x == 98) {  
//change color to blue
}
}

function red(event) {
var x = event.charCode || event.keyCode;
if (x == 82 || x == 114) {  
 //change color to red
}
}

function green (event) {
var x = event.charCode || event.keyCode;
if (x == 71 || x == 103) {  
 //change color to green
}
}

function yellow (event) {
var x = event.charCode || event.keyCode;
if (x == 89 || x == 121) {  
 //change color to yellow
}
}

function purple (event) {
var x = event.charCode || event.keyCode;
if (x == 80 || x == 112) {  
 //change color to purple
}
}
```

Comment: What you have is almost there, it just needs to be reorganized and expanded a little.  The big missing piece is `window.onkeyup`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you're trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/1qkL4kuk/1/

You're close with your approach, but you'll want to add a key listening function like this:

```
window.onkeyup = function(e) {
    var x = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    if (x == 66 || x == 98) {  
        fill = 'blue';
    } else if (x == 82 || x == 114) {  
        fill = 'red';
    } else if (x == 71 || x == 103) {  
        fill = 'green';
    } else if (x == 89 || x == 121) {  
        fill = 'yellow';
    } else if (x == 80 || x == 112) {  
        fill = 'purple';
    }
}
```

and within your draw function, you'll just need to have:

```
context.fillStyle = fill;
```

Comment: Thank you so  much for this, I also added a
    fill='black'; 
in the reset function to get it back to black!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("circles");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
//color to be used
var color = "#000000";

//a keycode and color mapping
var colorMap = {
  96: "#000000",
  65: '#000000',
  97: 'red',
  66: 'red',
  98: 'yellow',
  67: 'yellow'
};

function createImageOnCanvas(imageId) {
  canvas.style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("images").style.overflowY = "hidden";
  var img = new Image(300, 300);
  img.src = document.getElementById(imageId).src;
  context.drawImage(img, (0), (0)); //onload....
}

function draw(e) {
  var radius = document.getElementById("radius").value;

  var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
  posx = pos.x;
  posy = pos.y;
  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(posx, posy, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fill();

}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}

window.draw = draw;

function reset() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("circles");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = canvas.width;
}

//bind the handler to the element where the keypress should happen - you may want to filterout the input element here
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
  var x = event.charCode || event.keyCode;
  if (colorMap[x]) {
    color = colorMap[x];
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="images"></div>
<canvas id="circles" width="600" height="450" style="border:1px solid #000000;" onclick="draw(event)"></canvas>
<label for="radius">Enter circle radius:</label>
<input name="radius" id="radius" required autofocus />
<button onclick="reset()">reset!</button>
```